# what is all interfaces 0.0.0.0 in anypoint studio http connector?

Tags: mulesoft

[enter image description here][1]Can someone explain what does the Mulesoft Http Connector option All-interfaces (0.0.0.0) means . I know it's common and we do it almost every time but whats the significance and why do we use it ?

Comment: This is what I got from mulesoft website:
By default, the connector configuration has its host set to 0.0.0.0, this address is in fact a shortcut to simultaneously listen on all active IP addresses, (including localhost). In order to deploy a project to CloudHub, you must set the hosts of all the HTTP connectors to 0.0.0.0. Otherwise, your application runs into conflicts with the inner workings of CloudHub

Answer (score 1):

The ip address 0.0.0.0/0 is a special IP address which has different meanings in different contexts. More often it is used as a way to specify "any IPv4 address at all". It is used in this way when configuring servers (i.e. when binding listening sockets). This means the service is listening on all the configured network interfaces and can accept connection from "all ip addresses on your local machine."